# Feed string to the first Popen when several Popen are chained

Tags: python, pipe, popen

There is an answer to how to feed string to Popen by using Popen.communicate(intput=''). However, I have a problem of chaining several Popen like this:

```
p1 = Popen(['fstcompile', '--isymbols=ascii.syms', '--osymbols=ascii.syms'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(['fstprint', '--isymbols=ascii.syms', '--osymbols=ascii.syms'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
p1.stdout.close()
```

I would like to feed a string as stdin to p1 and then execute the whole sequence.

I tried the following:

```
p1.stdin.write('xxxx')
p1.stdin.flush()
print p2.communicate()[0]
```

and it didn't work.

Putting the string to `p2.communicate()[0]` makes no sense and it didn't work anyway.

So what's the right thing to do in such case?

Thank you in advance.